# Safari Image sizes on responsive site not consistent

Tags: image, safari, responsive-design, distortion

I would be very grateful for some help with a Safari image resizing issue as I have spent three days on this one problem.

I am building a responsive store with Woo Commerce using the Canvas template.

The problem is with the Safari browser...it won't enlarge the images to fit their container div and be evenly spaced and sized.

Here is a category page for your reference: http://omshivaloka.x-gr.net/product-category/shop/men-2/men-malas/

Here is a single product page, with the issue at the bottom beneath: "Products you may like": http://omshivaloka.x-gr.net/shop/hanuman/

I researched extensively all over the internet to find a solution and keep hearing to change the height and width in my CSS to:

ul.products li.product a img {

```
height: 100%!important;
width: 100%!important;
```

}

It's making them stretch, and is therefore not a solution.

In my Woo Commerce configuration, I have set the size of that picture to be 210*300px - Safari is not recognizing that...or maybe it is and is not outputting it immediately?

Perhaps you are having the same experience as I am in seeing the image expand when you mouse over it. Strange indeed...

I appreciate any help...thank you!

Cassandra

Comment: I'm having the same stretching issue in Safari 5, but Safari 6 is fine.

Comment: Just been digging around and you might find [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880150/responsive-site-image-issues) helpfull